# Angular - Element out of screen

Tags: angularjs

There is a way to check if a element is out of screen. In jQuery there is the :offscreen that check this. How can I do this using angular, without using jQuery?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that you need to know where an element is on the screen?  Most of the time, this kind of information isn't relevant to an angular application.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling and see if you can implement it in angular. Otherwise you may want to check this out for a 3rd party directive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling